# bash Loop through git cherry -v master and get first and last commit Id

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to write a batch file to try and get files which where modified after branch was created or after last merge to master branch.

I can do this simply in terminal like this:

```
git cherry -v master
git diff <first commit id> <last commit id> --name-only -- '*.jpg' '*.png' '*.gif'
```

But the issue I am facing with batch file is that the out put from git cherry -v master is like this :

```
+ c326be16a130a482debe5bcf7d5c4dbe396aa270 test
+ 4ff211dbc960724281ce75c3bb99024b6631a522 test 2
+ 4ff211dbc960724281ce75c3bb99024b6631a522 test 3
+ 4ff211dbc960724281ce75c3bb99024b6631a522 test 4
```

I only need that hash from first line and last line.

this is where I am at now:

```
echo
echo "--------------------------"
echo "Show commits after last merge to master"
echo "--------------------------"
echo

COMMITDIFFFROMMASTER=$(git cherry -v master)
echo "$COMMITDIFFFROMMASTER"
echo
echo "__________________________"
```

i am hoping to run git diff like this:

```
OUTPUT=$(git diff FIRSTCOMMIT LASTCOMMIT --name-only -- '*.jpg' '*.png' '*.gif')
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

I am very new to writing batch files. this is first time i am writing it. pls forgive if its a very stupid question.

Thanks

Comment: `I only need that hash from first line and last line.` i am not getting you what exactly you want? hash means `#`? if yes then where is `#`?

Comment: by hash i meant those SHA1s (example:4ff211dbc960724281ce75c3bb99024b6631a522) in each line of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this code works for you:

```
git cherry -v master|sed -n -e '1p' -e '$p'|awk '{print $2}'
```

To integrate it to you batch file:

```
first_last_commit=$(git cherry -v master|sed -n -e '1p' -e '$p'|awk '{print $2}')
OUTPUT=$(git diff ${first_last_commit} --name-only -- '*.jpg' '*.png' '*.gif')
echo "$OUTPUT"
```